# "Win the lottery", "win a lottery", "win lottery"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions, articles

Should it be *win the lottery* or *win a lottery* or just *win lottery?*

The sentences below sound the same to me. Are they?

> I lost $5000 to lottery.
>
> I lost $5000 for lottery.

Comment: Ironically, your question-title needs an article!

Answer (score 1):

*Win a lottery* and *win the lottery* would both be fine in certain contexts. In the US, many (most?) states have a *state lottery* with prizes in the millions of dollars. If I, in my home state of California, won the California State Lottery, I'd say, "I won the lottery." On the other hand, if a charitable organization sells numbered tickets and gives prizes to people whose numbers are drawn at random, as a way of raising money, that can be described as *a lottery*; if my number were drawn and I won $5,000, I could say, "I won it in a lottery."

I should also note, however, that I *wouldn't* say I won $5,000 "in a lottery;" I'd say I won it "in a raffle." I think it's more common (at least where I come from) to speak of *the lottery* (a big, state-sponsored drawing for millions of dollars) but *a raffle* (a drawing for smaller prizes, usually benefiting some sort of charity). Still, if someone said "a lottery," I'd know what they meant and wouldn't be confused.

I've never heard of anyone saying it with no article at all. Nor have I heard anyone saying they lost money "to lottery" or "for lottery." Also, lotteries, as I use the term, generally involve selling tickets for small amounts of money; $1 is common, and the most I've ever seen charged for a raffle ticket was $20. Someone could say, "I lost $5,000 on lottery tickets," but I'd be surprised if it happened all at once. Some people certainly do spend that much on lottery tickets over the course of a year, though.

Answer (score 0):

In a headline, or posted in a shop window: "Win Lottery" is just fine.  "Single Mother of 7 Wins Lottery!"

Comment: I don't think we should be overly concerned with the grammaticality of newspaper headlines.